# Why does Erdogan want to strengthen presidential system?

Tags: president, turkey

After he was the prime minister for 10+ years, which was the most powerful position in Turkish government, Erdogan became the president.  Now he wants to strengthen the presidential system.  I can't help but notice the resemblance between this move and the almost identical move V. Putin did in Russia.  Both men were the most powerful political figures in their countries as both prime minister and president.

Why does Erdogan want to strengthen the presidential system?  What are the declared benefits to his constituents aside, of course, from keeping him in the most powerful position?

**REFERENCES:**  [Erdogan aims to create stronger presidential system](http://www.al-monitor.com/pulse/originals/2015/02/turkey-erdogan-presidential-system-campaign.html#)

Comment: In Russia it is president which is the most powerful position since 1993. It has enormous power. The premier is nowhere near it.

Comment: Wait, do you really need any deeper answer than "he wants to keep the power"?

Comment: Might have something to do with him being president unless this is a coincidence.

Comment: I am protecting this question because someone keeps creating new accounts to post low-quality answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to provide more information besides the obvious reason already provided in the comments:

**keep and preferably increase his power**

Of course, one should not expect from an official to publicly recognize this as the main reason, but some of his declarations might be useful. According to [Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/turkey/12077703/Turkeys-president-says-all-he-wants-is-same-powers-as-Hitler.html):

- **showing working examples**:

> Mr Erdogan responded to arguments that putting political power in the
>   hands of the presidency would not work in a "unitary state".
>
> He said there were other examples of its being successful. "There are
>   already examples in the world,” he said.
>
> “You can see it when you look at Hitler's Germany. There are later
>   examples in various other countries."

- **it might provide justice**

> "What is important is that a presidential system should not disturb
>   the people in its implementation,” he said. “If you provide justice,
>   there will be no problem because what people want and expect is
>   justice."

- it is not that wrong because **it also happened in parliamentary systems** ([Whataboutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism)):

> There are authoritarian structures coming out of parliamentary
>   systems,” he said. “Hitler’s Germany was born out of a parliamentary
>   system."

This last point is a bit ironic since President Ergodan managed to increase his powers through [the popular vote in 2017](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/16/world/europe/turkey-referendum-polls-erdogan.html) (referendum).

Comment: "Don't worry too much about whether I become a dictator, I'm benevolent. Also, Hitler was cool."